# What is the downside of using third-party plugins in JIRA?

Tags: plugins, jira

We are considering using several third-party plugins (such as Structure) in JIRA.

Is it possible that after an upgrade of JIRA some of those third-party plugins will stop working? That would mean that our JIRA will become unusable, since those plugins are required for the workflow to function.

For example: 

 - JIRA issues a security patch, and a third-party plugin is not
   compatible with the patched JIRA version;

 - JIRA issues an update, and a third-party plugin is not compatible with the updated JIRA version.

Answer (score 0):

Put another way, if you install an add-on that is not well maintained, you may be forced to choose between delaying an upgrade or doing without the functionality (for a while). I recommend you view the version history of the add-on in Atlassian Marketplace and the issue tracker to get a sense of how "live" the add-on is. You may also be able to work with the add-on developer/company to expedite upgrades and development.

Of course, none of this advice is unique to JIRA or Atlassian tools.